# why chrome shows cookies for all domains in resources tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've opened Chrome's web developer tools (F12) and navigated to `Resources` tab. I then selected `Cookies` tab and clicked on cookies specific to my domain `inreado.git.local`. However the view showed cookies for domains other than mine, like `google.com` and others (see attached image)[image]. Why so? I'd expect only the cookies specific for my domain appear on the view.

Comment: Perhaps because these are third-party cookies that were set by resources that were embedded into the document you requested from inreado.git.local …?

Comment: Thanks, why I can't see them when going to `content settings` in `settings` menu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained in the Chrome DevTools [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/manage-data/cookies), that's because those cookies were set in iframes:

> Cookies are listed by domain. This includes the main document as well as all nested frames. Selecting one of these “frame groups” displays all cookies, for all resources, for all frames in that group. There are two consequences of this grouping to be aware of:
>
> - Cookies from different domains may appear in the same frame group.
> - The same cookie may appear in several frame groups.

Comment: Referenced Chrome DevTools documentation: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/devtools-docs/blob/master/docs/resource-panel.md#cookies